# Calculating a table of units with cost defined via vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this.[image]

In this example, I calculated the Totals with something by manually multiplying the unit counts (B2:E4) with the costs (B7:B10) of the appropriate product and summing each row.

My actual datais too complicated to do this manually.  What I would like to do is have a formula to automatically generate the Total column.  I imagine this is some magic combination of SUM, VLOOKUP & Array Formulas, but I've failed to find the solution.

Here is the [sample in spreadsheet form](https://www.dropbox.com/s/igemxy4ix8nls62/so_sample.xlsx?dl=0) if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier if you put the cost in row 2 under the various products.

Comment: That's an option.  I guess that really is significantly easier.

Edit:  Though, it's not apparent how I set up the calculation in this configuration either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine a lookup with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LOOKUP($B$1:$E$1,$A$7:$A$10,$B$7:$B$10))*B2:E2)
```

[image]

---

If the cost were in row 2 a simple SUMPRODUCT would suffice:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$E$2,B3:E3)
```

[image]